# What's the regex for key=value, delimited by commas?

Tags: java, regex

What's the Java regular expression that captures the entire key-value list (shown in bold in the example below)?

> foo bar **k0=v0, k1=v1, k2=v2** foo bar

The keys and values do not contain whitespace characters, `,` or `=`.

I've tried: `(([^\s,=]+=[^\s,=]+),?)+` at [Regular Expression Test Page for Java](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html), but it gives me groups of the individual equalities (`k0=v0`, etc) instead of the entire string. Why is that? and how do I fix it?

Comment: What if the key value pairs are all over the place? Isn't returning separate items better?

Comment: I only need to know where this list occurs in the string, and it only occurs in one section of the string. The key-values themselves are irrelevant to me.

Comment: If you want to know whether the list is there or not, testing for **one** key-value pair is sufficient, no need to test for the whole list.

Comment: I also need to know where it starts and ends.

Comment: Please state your end purpose of doing the whole thing in the question next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp does not allow spaces. If you want it to also include spaces, you can't get rid of `"foo bar"` around it (it will assume it's a part of a key or value). If you just want to allow spaces after a comma, try this:

```
(([^\s,=]+=[^\s,=]+)(?:,\s*)?)+
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following would work:

```
([^=|^,|^\W]+)=([^,|^\W]+)
```